# Deleting Records from huge MySQL innoDB Table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know this question has been asked a hundred times, but unfortunately none of these answers helped, since most are many many years old, it should justify another one.

I have two tables, `records` with `+140kk rows/+24GB` and `extra` with `+89kk rows/+70GB`.

Every `extra` row has a foreign key relation to `records`, indexes are properly set between the two tables. Deletions from `records` cascade a delete to the related `extra` row.

I need to clear old records **during production**. 
Running `DELETE FROM records WHERE WHERE created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000;` takes endless (I killed it after 20 minutes where it was still in `init`). Doing the same with `SELECT` finishes in just a few milliseconds.

Since the `SELECT` is that fast I tried it with an `id IN (SELECT id subquery^)`, unfortunately that didn't change a thing, so I killed it after 15 minutes.

Since deleting single records is fast, I ended up with this work around:

```sh
for i in `seq 1 100000`; do
    mysql database -e "SELECT id FROM records WHERE created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000;" | sed 's;/|;;g' | awk '{if(NR>1)print "DELETE FROM records WHERE id = ",$1,";" }' | mysql database;
    now=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")
    echo "[ $now ] $i.000"
done
```

This is able to deal with a thousand records per second at the beginning but after a few loops it goes down to a thousand per 10-20 seconds. As I need to purge 100k rows this would take nearly a month to finish, which is about the same timeframe the records to purge are from, hence it would never finish (especially as there are multiple databases which need this).

The database is stored on an SSD `Crucial_CT500MX200SSD1` and the Software is `MariaDB 10.1` with the `InnoDB` engine. `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` is set to `0` to avoid unnecessary disk util.

According to `atop` the bottleneck is the Disk, CPU is nearly sleeping and most of the mem is in system cache.

Structure dump: https://gist.github.com/Slind14/0da34e09dba91cf411db2ead5ad666ef

Comment: Do you need that ORDER BY id in the first query?Try it without it.

Comment: That is required to avoid replication issues. Doesn't make a difference as long as it is ASC (default order).

Comment: AFAIK `ORDER BY id` can't use the index after a range check in the WHERE clause. Did you try without ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Comment: The select returns within milliseconds hence the limit and order by are not an issue. The `LIMIT` is required to do it in chunks as this a production database we can't lock the table for a day. The `ORDER BY` is required to make the query deterministic, otherwise it would break replication.

Comment: Are the ids in the same sequence as `created`?

Comment: can i have some more information ? Please send us the output of **SELECT * FROM prism_extra   LIMIT 1000 PROCEDURE ANALYSE();** and **SELECT * FROM prism_records LIMIT 1000 PROCEDURE ANALYSE();** (!! it can use some minutes) and also run your delete query and when it use a long time run **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

It discusses various ways to efficiently delete lots of rows from big tables.

The one that will probably work best is to walk through the table based on the `PRIMARY KEY` (it has such?), deleting whichever rows in that chunk match the criteria.

The reason this is efficient is that it looks at, say, 100 rows at a time, works with them, and only then moves on to the next 100 rows.  In contrast, using `LIMIT` and unbounded `WHERE` clauses can require scanning the same rows over and over.

You mentioned a `JOIN`.  Depending on how costly that is, 100 may be a good limit.  If the `JOIN` is not too onerous, perhaps 1000 would work well.

If this will be a recurring task, consider using `PARTITIONing` so that `DROP PARTITION` can be used to 'instantly' do the deed.

Comment: what type of syntax is this? I'm not able to get it work in a procedure.

Comment: Pseudo-code; it needs to be converted to whatever language you are using.  (I tend to avoid Stored Procedure because I find them more clumsy than PHP or Perl.)  What language were you writing in?

Comment: The app this database is from is in java. But I would prefer a nodejs/php or even bash/perl script. Any recommendation?

Comment: In Perl, I always use `DBIx::DWIW`.  But use what you are comfortable with.